# How to run Kafka as a stream for Apache Spark using Scala 2.11?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I haven't been able to find any any build of Spark Streaming integration for Kafka for Scala 2.11. There is a one available here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10 but it is for 2.10

Can anyone point me to a 2.11 build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Specific to your question:

It's not feasible to run Spark Kafka against Scala 2.11 by now (`Spark-1.3`)

#### General method to build from source code:

If no pre-build version available, you could build spark yourself and fulfil your needs by specifying some build parameters.

The detailed build procedure could be find: [Building Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html)

In short, It would only take two steps if build against scala-2.10:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m"

mvn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests clean package
```

*You should specify profiles or properties that fits your situation in the second command*

Note the part [Building Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html) states on `Building for Scala 2.11`:

> To produce a Spark package compiled with Scala 2.11, use the -Dscala-2.11 property:
>
> `dev/change-version-to-2.11.sh` 
>   `mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package`
>
> Scala 2.11 support in Spark does not support a few features due to dependencies which are themselves not Scala 2.11 ready. **Specifically, Spark’s external Kafka library and JDBC component are not yet supported in Scala 2.11 builds.**

Comment: Current Spark doc (1.5.1) no longer mentions Kafka as unsupported for 2.11.

Comment: And it is no longer experimental. After building Spark from source with 2.11, it worked fine for me.